# Cfquery apparently not working using argument value for WHERE

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

we have an upload form that can called from various parts of our editing app. A field in this form gets populated based on where it is called from. So, if a user is on the Overview page and uses the form, the field in question gets populated with "Overview." In testing, the field does indeed get populated correctly and the form field value does get posted.

I pass this value to our CFC as an argument:

```
<cfargument name="imageType" type="string" required="true" default="">
```

I then use it to run a query:

```
<cfquery name="getImageType">
    SELECT ID AS imageTypeID
    FROM tbl_imagetypes
    WHERE type = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.imageType#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>
```

I then use the resulting imageTypeID to update a few other tables, like this:

```
<cfquery name="addNewImageJoin" datasource="vertipedia" result="AddNewJoinResult">
    INSERT INTO tbl_imageJoins (imageID,aircraftID,imageTypeID,isPrimary)
    VALUES (
            <cfqueryparam value="#AddNewImageResult.generated_key#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.aircraftID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#getImageType.imageTypeID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">,
            <cfqueryparam value="no" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
            )
</cfquery>
```

The trouble is, it doesn't work! I don't get any errors back, but my other tables never get updated, either. However, when I comment out the above query and hardcode all the other queries (replacing #getImageType.imageTypeID# with "1" for example), they work fine.

I have been looking at this for a while, but I can't see any reason why it would not work. I hope it is something silly that I am just missing because I have been staring at it for so long! I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or advice.

Thank you all in advance! BTW, again, the value of the "imageType" form field is getting posted -- at least, I can see it along with the values of all the other fields in Firebug.

Comment: What do you see if you dump the getImageType query?

Comment: Haha! I am an idiot. I forgot to include the datasource! I set up the cfc to email the cfdumps to myself, per your suggestion, and did not get anything. So I commented out the offending query, hardcoded the other values, and voila, email. So there was SOMETHING about that one query, lol... yeah it took me a while to see it, but you can see for yourself in my original code examples: no datasource! :-)  So thanks a lot, Dan! Not sure how to mark your comment as an answer, but it is -- you definitely got me going in the right direction. I appreciate it!

Comment: You can set a default datasource in `application.cfc`. It makes for less typing.

Comment: Thanks, James, that is a good idea! This particular application uses more than one datasource, though. Could I set a default in application.cfc and then override it for those queries that do not use the default? Hmm I will try that. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Just a side note: an argument is either required or has a default value. It makes no sense to have both.

Comment: Yes you can set a default datasource in your app, and the supply the datasource for queries where it's different.

Comment: Thanks everybody -- I have set a defalt datasource and am updating my various queries now. Coincidentally, I was at an event yesterday where the presenter noted that having a default datasource may even result in modest performance increases.